# Querying a table to get values based on no of digits of a parameter?

Tags: ms-access

Considering the following table

I have a large table from which I can query to get the following table

```
type       no of times type occurs
101            450
102            562
103            245
111            25
112            28
113            21
```

Now suppose I wanted to get a table which shows me the sum of no of times type occurs
for type starting with 1 then starting with 10,11,12,13.......19 then starting with 2, 20,21, 22, 23...29 and so on.

Something like this

```
1        1331               10        1257
                            11        74
                            12         ..
                            13         ..
                            ..         ..
2        ...                20         ..
                            21         ..
```

Hope I am clear
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have two different queries:

```
SELECT [type]\100 AS TypePart, Count(t.type) AS CountOftype
FROM t
GROUP BY [type]\100;
```

And:

```
SELECT [type]\100 AS TypePart, [type] Mod 100 AS TypeEnd, 
    Count(t.type) AS CountOftype
FROM t
GROUP BY [type]\100, [type] Mod 100;
```

Where t is the name of the table.

Comment: i think teh second query is not quite right should nt Count(t.type) AS CountOftype be count(t.nooftimestypeoccurs)as counofnotype

Comment: Not if the name of the field in the big table is Type.

Comment: it is counting the no times type occurs but i want it to add the no of time occuring values for the same  hope i am clear

Answer (score 0):

Here on the first query i am getting something like this

```
utypPart    CountOftype
    1   29
    2   42
    3   46
    4   50
    5   26
    6   45
    7   33
    9   1
```

it is giving me how many utyp are starting with 1 2 and so on
but whai i want is the sum of no of times those types occur for the utyp .